# What is wrong with the shell script for curl post command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i need help in understanding what is wrong with the below shell script,all its doing is executing a `curl`  script using `shell scripting` and searching for a string `domain_id` in the output of curl command ,once it finds the search all it does it simply displays `valid url`

Here is the full code for shell script below

```
#!/bin/sh
# Black Box Tester!
url=”https://api.platform.abc.com/auth/oauth/token“
content=”$(curl  --location --request POST “$url” --header 'Content-Type:    
application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Authorization: Basic   
V0pSWURISA==' --data-raw 'grant_type=password&username=event-
player1@abc.com&password=********' | grep domain_id”
 if [ ! -z $content ] && [ $content -eq domain_id ]
then
echo “valid url”
else
echo “invalid url”
fi
```

Below is the error i get in console after i try executing the script

```
WS-126691A:loginimagedocker carolyn$ ./login.sh
./login.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./login.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: `unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')'` is pretty clear -- you have an opening parenthesis at `$(curl ...` and there is no closing parenthesis. Looks like you'd want the close just before the grep `...dvmHB') | grep domain_id”` or after it `VdvmHB' | grep domain_id”)`  (but I didn't try it)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass parameter in multiple line without mentioning end of line.

use \ to pass multi line argument

```
#!/bin/sh
# Black Box Tester!
url=”http://api.platform.abc.com/auth/oauth/token“
content=”$(curl  --location --request POST “$url” --header 'Content-Type: \
application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Authorization: Basic    \
V0pSWURISA==' --data-raw 'grant_type=password&username=event- \
player1@abc.com&password=********' | grep domain_id” )

 if [ ! -z $content ] && [ $content -eq domain_id ]
then
echo “valid url”
else
echo “invalid url”
fi
```